# How to bulk delete user accounts in Firebase server side?

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

Throughout the testing of an app I've built using Firebase, I've created a large number of phony accounts. I was wondering if there's an easy way to delete all of them before the app goes live?

I could just go through and delete them one by one but there is a large number of accounts and that is a really last resort sort of option.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those accounts are for testing reasons, I am not sure whether or not you have kept track of all the account names and passwords. If you have, for example in your database or in a local file. What you can do is:

1st, use the user data stored in the file to perform login

then,

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.delete().then(function() {
  // emmit a complete message
}, function(error) {
  // handle error
});
```

perform this on all the users in the file.

If you don't have all the users' information, I don't think firebase allows you to delete them in your client side code. You have to delete them in your firebase console I guess.

Comment: Same code, but I'd suggest using the Firebase Admin SDK for this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user

Comment: Thanks so much, this is perfect!